# set SSL to Domain name for MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

I have to setup SSL connection for MYSQL with domain name. Database server running on Ubuntu 18 LTS. So i have to setup SSL for domain name in MYSQL database server. I have referred some documents which are like default ssl in mysql. Is possible to setup SSL for domain name in MYSQL database then Kindly tell me the steps to be done or refer me with some documents.

Comment: Question seems to be confused. If it's a about Linux setting, I'll suggest to use https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to setup SSL for domain name in MYSQL database.

By default, MySQL is configured to only accept local connections. If you need to allow remote connections, it is important to do so securely.

So here is the demonstrate to configure MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04 to accept remote connections with SSL/TLS encryption.

might help you
thanks

Comment: Sorry, from your answer "here is the demonstrate ...", so what is "here" ?